# HyperPay credit card payment not woking in iOS in live enviorment

Tags: android, ios, flutter, payment

Credit card payment in live enviorment is working perfectly fine in android developed in flutter using flutter hyper pay pluggin but the same code not working in the iOS giving error

PlatformException(0.2, invalid or missing parameter - (opp) No payment session found for the requested id - are you mixing test/live servers or have you paid more than 30min ago?, , null)

Any idea?

trying to get the credit card otp page as getting in android

Answer (score 0):

based on your exception you use test checkoutId not live try to change mode to test and try again with this chechoutId

Comment: OP is trying to fix their _live_ environment.